# Where is linux automount's config?

Tags: centos, nfs, mount, automount

I have a centos box, it has some NFS mounts. I'm trying to figure out these NFS filesystems get mounted. And I figured out if I rename /usr/sbin/automount to some else name, after reboot the box, those NFS will not be mount. So I can be sure that automount does those NFS mounts.

But /etc/auto.master show nothing about those NFS's info. I wonder what possibilities there could be about how automount how which NFS to mount?

```
$ cat /etc/auto.master
#
# Sample auto.master file
# This is an automounter map and it has the following format
# key [ -mount-options-separated-by-comma ] location
# For details of the format look at autofs(5).
#
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
#
# NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
#   "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev" 
#   options are explicitly given.
#
/net    -hosts
#
# Include central master map if it can be found using
# nsswitch sources.
#
# Note that if there are entries for /net or /misc (as
# above) in the included master map any keys that are the
# same will not be seen as the first read key seen takes
# precedence.
#
+auto.master
```

But under `/var/run`, I find somethings like the following:

```
prw-------  1 root      root         0 Jan 20 04:36 autofs.fifo-bldmnt
prw-------  1 root      root         0 Jan 20 04:36 autofs.fifo-blr
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/auto.master`?

Comment: isn't the map should be in /etc/auto.misc?

Comment: Can you disable autofs at book (chkconfig autofs off), reboot and confirm that autofs is actually auto mounting your nfs mount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file auto.master usually contains this line:

```
/net    -hosts
```

An older alternative is (was):

```
/net    /etc/auto.net
```

The first line is the so called builtin map referring to the file /etc/hosts
and the second example is a so called program map (usually a simple shell script), which may better explain to you how the automounter works.

I guess you have some symbolic links on your system pointing to some path 
on remote servers under `/net` (or whatever autofs path prefix is used instead 
of /net in your copy of the `/etc/auto.master`).

Whenever a path below the `/net` anchor is visited the automounter catches this
attempt and tries to mount the referenced directory there.

### Example:

Assume the automounter is running and in the network there exists a NFS server named `HostA` which exports a directory named `Documents` in his `/etc/exports` file.  Then using the command

```
cd /net/HostA/Documents
```

can automatically mount this remote directory there without further configuration on the NFS client.

### Internals:

Like other services automount uses named pipes for some internal interprocess communication.  So the files in `/var/run/` mentioned in the question are created by the automount process for this purpose prior to really mounting anything.

In early versions of the autofs package `/etc/auto.net` was a script which calls
the command `showmount` or `kshowmount --no-headers -e` NFS-SERVER to obtain a list of exported filesystems from the NFS server.

`showmount` on the client displays the directories defined in the file `/etc/exports` on the server side.  This file might contain the directory `/`.
But due to security concerns this was never the default on any Linux distribution I've ever seen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my update in the question.

Comment: There is the extreme and unlikely possibility, since he doesn't sound responsible for configuring it himself, that the site uses NIS/YP or LDAP. His automount daemon may be getting it's maps from a different nss provider?

Comment: @pefu @etherfish Thanks for your explanation. I think I'm closing to the answer. The only thing I'm still confused is that on my server, NFS server name folder is created under `/`. Is `/` the default dir that automount will check?

Answer (score 0):

We have a few RHEL6 systems which should be somehow similar to centOS machines.
Our server-settings are in /etc/exports

```
/data/nfs     <IP-Range>(rw,sync,insecure,root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)

/data/nfs/data <IP-Range>(rw,nohide,sync,insecure,root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

and on the clients the settings are in /etc/fstab

```
<Hostname of NFS-Server>:/data    /data/<mount-directory>      nfs4     rw     0 0
```